# Cannot make an outlet of a label

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, viewcontroller, outlet

I am working on an application with tab views. In one of the tabs I have several labels. I want to make an outlet foreach of the labels, but clicking control and dragging it to the ViewController file doesn't do the trick for me. I think it has something to do with the tabs but I can't figure what the exact problem is. How can I add the label to the ViewController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In storyboard, you need to set the `ViewController`'s class first, then you can connect the labels:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick! Couldn't find anything about that in the forums

Comment: You're welcome. It's just something you need to learn once (in whatever way), then you'll never forget :)